# Smarty PHP add an {if} statement and include a tpl

Tags: php, smarty3

I am currently using Smarty-php for the first time, I am struggling however with placing a if statement around the {include} below.

```
{include './header.tpl'}
```

Everytime I do the following I get a 500 error.

```
{if $smarty.get.special is not "ajax"}
    {include './header.tpl'}
{/if}
```

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: Why is this question about smarty and PHP, and yet it is tagged with task-parallel-library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
{if $smarty.get.special != "ajax"}
    {include file='./header.tpl'}
{/if}
```

The `is [not]` syntax can be used to check if a value is (or is not) even or odd.